# Numpy: if then else on new column , using new strings for THEN and ELSE

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to do a Pandas IF then Else statement in a new column. I couldn't find any questions where people used write in their own strings or "Yes"/"No".

Trying to do the following logic, If col A = Col B, then No Else Yes.

```
enterprisehr['Change_Dept'] = np.select([enterprisehr['Dept_Descr'] == enterprisehr['Old_Dept_Descr']], "No", "Yes")
```

I am getting this error: `ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions`

Should I be using numpy here to do this? How can I write my own values in, ie "No"/"Yes".

Sample Data /Expectation:

[image]

Comment: why don't you provide your data as text and expected output?

Comment: ok will do , give me a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's `select` is expecting the choice list to be the same length as the condition list. Use [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to choose between two values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

enterprisehr = pd.DataFrame({'Dept_Descr': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                             'Old_Dept_Descr': ['A', 'B', 'X']})

condition = enterprisehr['Dept_Descr'] == enterprisehr['Old_Dept_Descr']

enterprisehr['Change_Dept'] = np.where(condition, "No", "Yes")
print(enterprisehr)
```

Output:

```
  Dept_Descr Old_Dept_Descr Change_Dept
0          A              A          No
1          B              B          No
2          C              X         Yes
```

Note that I also removed the square brackets from around the condition statement so that `condition` is a Pandas Series object that isn't wrapped in  list.

Answer (score 1):

for np.select

```
x = np.arange(10)

condlist = [x<3, x>5]

choicelist = [x, x**2]

np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

length of condlist and choicelist should be same

you can also use np.where
syntax:

```
numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
```

example:

```
x = np.where(x>40, 4, 0) + np.where(x>50, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, can this be done on strings too? I am not using numbers in my columns.

Comment: yes it can be used for any data types.